# Error is generating even function is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Click action generates this error message while function is defined
**Uncaught typeError: undefined is not a function**

Click left arrow makes all html invisible while code isn't deleted by jquery.
**[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ze4z6/)**

```
var left='.lessonNavigation li.expanded.left'  
var actLsn='.lessonNavigation li.activeLesson'  
var right='.lessonNavigation li.expanded.right'  
var leftArrowHTML='<li class="left arrow"><i class="icon icon-arrow-left"></i></li>'  
var rightArrowHTML='<li class="right arrow"><i class="icon icon-arrow-right"></i></li>'

$('.lessonNavigation').on('click', '.left.arrow', function () {   
    $(right).attr('class','dn');  
    $('.arrow').remove();  
    $(actLsn).attr('class','expanded right');
    $(left).attr('class','activeLesson');  
    $(actLsn).previous().attr('class','expanded left');  
    $(actLsn).after(rightArrowHTML);  
    $(actLsn).before(leftArrowHTML);  
});
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="lessonNavigation lesson">
    <ul class="expandable">
        <li class=""><b>L1</b><span>Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</span></li>
        <li class="expanded left"> <b>L2</b><span>Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</span></li>
        <li class="left arrow"><i class="icon icon-arrow-left"></i></li>
        <li class="activeLesson"><b>L3</b><span>Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</span></li>
        <li class="right arrow"><i class="icon icon-arrow-right"></i></li>
        <li class="expanded right"><b>L4</b><span>Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</span></li>
        <li class=""><b>L5</b><span>Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</span></li>
        <li class=""><b>L6</b><span>Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't reproduce the problem as it's incomplete. Could you update it?

Comment: As you click left arrow there, you see all design goes away.

Comment: Try `prev()` instead of `previous()`

Comment: What are you trying to archive?

Comment: The fiddle is missing the definitions of all the variables, and gets an error when it tries to access `right`.

Comment: @kmsdev Post that as an answer

Comment: Variables are defined now in jsFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `prev()` instead of `previous()` :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no method called `.previous()` in jQuery

It is supposed to be `.prev()`

Also why do you want to overwrite the class attribute.

You can use `addClass` and `removeClass` methods

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of undefined variables, but for starters you can't pass in more selectors to your click handler. Try something like this.

```
$('.lessonNavigation li.left.arrow').on('click', function () {
   $(this).attr('class','dn');
    $('.arrow').remove();
    $(actLsn).attr('class','expanded right');
    $('.lessonNavigation li.expanded.left').addClass('activeLesson');
    $('.lessonNavigation li.expanded.left').attr('class','activeLesson');
    $(actLsn).previous().attr('class','expanded left');
    $(actLsn).after(rightArrowHTML);
    $(actLsn).before(leftArrowHTML);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ze4z6/2/

I don't know where your variables for actLsn are... do you mean $(this) like I did on line 2?

Comment: Yes, you can pass in a selector in the `on` call. That is used to create a delegated event. http://api.jquery.com/on/